# Maven:how to check which jars are not being used at all

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

We have a multiwar project and with various people working on the project a lot of times, lots of unused jars are still specified as dependencies, is there any way , to check which jars are not used at all, but nonetheless, are being referred to as a dependency?

I hope maven already has support for something like this, considering its such a powerful tool.

Comment: To be clear, you'd like your application to run for a certain amount of time (presumably until all the classes that are going to be loaded are loaded), and then to check for jars are on the classpath that were never actually ever used?

Comment: Yes that would be an ideal case to catch hold of jars not being used at all.For the process you have mentioned I might need a code-coverage tool probably.Also, just to add colour to the discussion, all the projects are using spring, so all the classess being used should be instantiated the the very beginning of the application initialization phase.

Comment: I am sure there are tools able to do this but keep in mind some dependencies cannot be determined through static analysis only. For example classes loaded by name stored in a text property and similar.

Comment: Agreed dynamic, run-time dependencies are impossible to determine at compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:analyze`. It should do the work.

Comment: that only gives me a graph of the dependencies right? or does it tell me what all dependecies are not being used as well? If the former is the case, then the graph is actually just a dependency graph which is derived from the pom.xml I have mentioned.

Comment: @Stephenc yes it seems that doing a mvn dependency:analyze mentions a list of unused declared dependencies, which is the subset of dependencies I was looking for.

Comment: At the same time, I should mention that dependency:analyze might not suffice for my specific case, as with a multi-war project, I am not sure I can do a dependency:analyze which will merge the results of all the wars , i.e used and unused dependencies and return a set of unused declared dependencies across wars and not just for a single war.