# About the memory space occupied by 3rd-party jar packages

Tags: java, jvm

There are more than two hundred jar files in my java project and I want to save memory space of jvm procedure. Does the number of 3rd-party jar packages have great impact on memroy occupy?

[image: jstat command]

Refer to the metaspace size, old region?

How to figure out the exact space occupied by 3rd-party jar packages?

Comment: The third party JAR files will definitely increase the size of your WAR or executable file.  But, they should only take up memory in the JVM as the JVM loads particular classes from each of the packages.  So, obviously if you have JARs in there which aren't even being used, you may delete them.

Comment: I see. is there a effective methods to find out the unused jars in java project? mvn dependency:analyze maybe a way for this,but it can not be sure  the Unused declared dependencies is really not used in my project

Comment: [Maven:how to check which jars are not being used at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133164/mavenhow-to-check-which-jars-are-not-being-used-at-all)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. also I want to extract the common jar files used by both project  to a common directory and make them used in common like tomcat shared library. Is this a way to save memory occupy or should I say it will have great impact on memory occupy reduction

Comment: Hi Time, I've tried mvn dependency:analyze,but seem the result is incorrect, for example:spring-boot-starter-jdbc is used in java file, but it appear in Unused declared dependencies found section.Did I miss something?